# Coding a Flowchart

Tags: osx, workflow

I'm looking for a professional tool for OSX that using a DSL will allow me to write code for a workflow and will generate a flowchart from the code.  Something similar to [this](http://www.code2flow.com/) but not in-browser and providing a little more functionality (like compressing the chart).

This tool should:

1. Allow input of "code" as text that will influence the generation of the flow chart
2. Provide the ability to draw-to-file a flowchart graph from the code input
3. Provide manual modifications to the flowchart such as moving boxes to different positions, changing box size, changing box shape, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically list features rather than similar to x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with LaTeX, then I recommend using the [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package in a `standalone` document class. The [manual](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) describes the syntax in detail, and you can find flowchart examples [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/).

Pros (matching your criteria):

1. Allows input of code using any text editor and can be built using your local LaTeX interpretor, or even an [online tool](https://www.writelatex.com/docs?snip_uri=http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/TEX/simple-flow-chart.tex&splash=none)
2. The resulting diagram is saved in PostScript/PDF format, which can be converted to high density graphics using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) `convert -density 600x600 flowchart.pdf -quality 100 flowchart.png`. This can by typed later in the command line, or added to the document class to output the image in a single step `\documentclass[convert={density=600,outext=.png}]{standalone}`.
3. Provides control over the size and shape of the nodes using `\tikzstyle{}` and the ability to fine tune positions by the millimeter (or your preferred unit, `pt` for example). You can also save your own style definitions in a separate file and `\input{}` it into several documents, instead of copying or typing them all over again.

Cons:

1. Might take time to learn if you are new to LaTeX

Comment: I'm afraid to use LaTeX because there's too much control given to the user.  For example, I don't want to worry about millimeter node positions, I'd rather have that taken care of for me.  Do you know if TikZ can perform its own optimal node spacing?

Comment: @fifosine In the linked [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/), they have used a global node distance with ``auto`` mode (``\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]``). This means that you won't have to worry about individual node spacing except in special cases.